# Why isn't another member of a group able to use a directory?

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

I have created a directory named `IDE` in `/opt` using following command

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/IDE
```

Then I have changed the owner of `IDE` directory.

```
sudo chown shantanu:csedev /opt/IDE
```

Above command works fine and changed the owner successfully. But I can't give `write permission` to `/opt/IDE` for group. Following command is not working.

```
sudo chmod g+w /opt/IDE
ls -l /opt
```

## output

```
drwxrw-r-x 3 shantanu csedev 4096 Apr 9 14:50 IDE
```

I have another user named `developer` who is the the member of group `csedev`. But I can't write in `/opt/IDE` from `developer` user.

Also I don't understand the meaning of first permission section of `ls` command. `drwxrw`, there is too many permission, isn't it?

Comment: The directory lacks execute permissions for group - other members of the group won't be able to enter it.

Comment: @muru Thanks you for quick reply. What is the meaning of drwxrw (4th w)?

Comment: It means users can modify the directory (I think adding and removing files, updating timestamps, etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the execute bit set for the group on the directory too to be able to *search for directories* and allow members permission to *enter the directory*:

```
chmod g+x /opt/IDE
```

Comment: At this point, sudo isn't needed. OP owns the directory.

Comment: @A.B. It works, but I don't understand, Why should I give executable permission? Then what is the difference between g+rw or g+rwx??

Comment: How muru already wrote: _The directory lacks execute permissions for group - other members of the group won't be able to enter it._